# Google Cloud Secret Manager - Create a secret in a region

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm working with the Python library google-cloud-secret-manager and I'm facing some problems in creating a secret within a defined region.

In the method **secretmanager.create_secret** seems that there is a metadata parameter that can be filled but I keep receiving errors trying something like:

```
metadata=[{'region': 'europe-west1'}]
```

The library code below for me is not very clear on these parameters...

This is the original snippet I'm trying to execute:

```
response = secret_client.create_secret(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "secret_id": secret_id,
            "secret": {"replication": {"automatic": {}}},
        }
    )
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT

Following the full code, taken from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets), where it is not specified how to specify the region...

```
def create_secret(project_id, secret_id):
"""
Create a new secret with the given name. A secret is a logical wrapper
around a collection of secret versions. Secret versions hold the actual
secret material.
"""

# Import the Secret Manager client library.
from google.cloud import secretmanager

# Create the Secret Manager client.
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

# Build the resource name of the parent project.
parent = f"projects/{project_id}"

# Create the secret.
response = client.create_secret(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "secret_id": secret_id,
        "secret": {"replication": {"automatic": {}}},
    }
)

# Print the new secret name.
print("Created secret: {}".format(response.name))
```

Comment: Can you detail what is worked, what is not, and what are the errors?

Comment: Please provide reproduction steps and the error you're getting so we can troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, please find in the original question the full code. I'm not getting errors because I can't find how to specify the region in the function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify the replication key placement manually, you need to specify it like in the example below:

```
response = client.create_secret(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "secret_id": secret_id,
        "secret": {"user_managed": {
               "replicas": [
                    {"location": "europe-west1"}
                ]}
        },
    }
)
```

Comment: you can check the protobuf type implementation of the `Replication` class in python library here https://github.com/googleapis/python-secret-manager/blob/ef9d0ea8690ccd42f554ac9b3c368c5dfbc62c87/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/types/resources.py#L189

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer ist not working for me. There is a layer above "user_managed" which is "replication". Here is my snippet:

```
client.create_secret(
    request={
        "parent": f"projects/<project_id>",
        "secret_id":"<secret_name>",
        "secret": {"replication": {"user_managed": {"replicas":[{"location": "<region_name>"}]}}},
    }
)
```

Exchange the values in the brackets ("<", ">") whit your own values.